# Design Help Required in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin4spring, vaadin-charts, vaadin6

Hope you are fine and doing good.

Im new in VAADIN and my seniors give a task to create a website using VAADIN but im facing a alot of difficulties in VAADIN for creating HTML,CSS etc. Designer gives me website design in PSD/JPG format and i have to implement those in VAADIN. but how....

Please help me or guide me. if you any any video tutorial link on this please share it with me.

I have sound knowledge in HTML5, CSS3, JQUERY, BOOTSTRAP, RESPONSIVE Webdesign.

Inshort my question is how can i create webpage from PSD to HTML using vaadin

Comment: You have to style the different elements like you received in the PSD file. For this you use a default theme and then adapt the look&feel. As for the general screen layout, you usually work with different Layout elements, like HorizontalLayout etc. https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

The Vaadin framework has changed a lot over the last few years, just be careful in searching for answers that you get the latest information. The [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/intro.html) is a great place to start. The [Demo Sampler](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/) also gives you code examples (the icons in Menu provide various code details).